# App crashes when closed

Tags: iphone, ios, crash

When I close my app (double tap home button and touch the X) on my iPhone, it crashes and I get this error:

```
objc[9337]: class `ADManager' not linked into application
objc[9337]: class `ADSessionManager' not linked into application
objc[9337]: class `ADSession' not linked into application
(lldb)
```

-Deployment target: iOS 5.1
-Iphone iOS 5.1.1
-Testing with Xcode on iPhone

How can I fix it?

Comment: You might want post some more code, and what version of Xcode are you running?

Comment: I'm using Xcode Version 4.3.3 (4E3002). What code should I post? I don't know what code will help. I can post MasterView.h/.m, DetailView.h/.m & AppDelegate.h/.m. When I disconnect my iPhone from my mac, the app is working perfectly. That is strange.

Comment: Is that error you are getting from the Xcode console or via symbolication? Is your app allowed to run in the background?

Comment: Yes, I get it from Xcode. No, my app isn't allowed to run in the background.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the default behavior of all iOS apps in iOS4 and later.

Answer (score 1):

Um, it's not a good idea to be running the app connected to Xcode debugger and then terminate it in the middle of the process. It can very easily lead to the bootstrap error.

The debugger is constantly monitoring your app when you run it in iTunes, terminating it would obviously cause a crash =/

You can see a spinning icon in the "debug" tab in Xcode 4 (the tab with the icon that looks like a speech button and some lines in it in your project navigator) when you're in the middle of debugging.

Not sure what you're trying to achieve by terminating your app, a registered background process such as location service?

Comment: I only wanted to close my app. Nothing else. And then I get this error and I was confused/worried that my app is useless. But now everything is ok. Next time I will test my app after disconnecting from iTunes.